# Why does my eslint automation return this error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, client-server, eslint

I have set up eslint to check my two js files. When I run eslint ./file1.js ./file2.js the eslint works fine however when i try to automate it by adding it to my package.json file like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node file1.js"
    "pretest": "eslint .\file1.js .\file2.js"

  },
```

and try to run it by using 'npm run pretest' in my CLI it returns this error, rather than running normally like it does when I type the eslint command directly in my CLI:

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file C:\filepath\package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 148 while parsing '{
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "name": "progproj",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "ve'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\filepath\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-18T00_05_33_552Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Why are the f's escaped?

Comment: I think it's just a typo in your `package.json` - comma is missing after `"node file1.js"`.

Comment: @epascarello sorry what does this mean ?

Comment: @user14967413 it didnt work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful with windows path files in package.json. You can scape them with "whatever/andever"

Then your script could look like:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node file1.js",
  "pretest": "eslint \".\file1.js\" \".\file2.js\""

},
```

Or as they point to the project folder you could do:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node file1.js",
    "pretest": "eslint file1.js file2.js"

  },
```

Comment: The second ones output is: `npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file C:\filepath\programming-project\package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token e in JSON at position 162 while parsing near '...",
npm ERR! JSON.parse     "pretest": ""eslint \".\main.js\"...'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\filepath\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-18T02_17_43_584Z-debug.log`

Comment: sadly both of these seem to produce a similar error

Comment: I corrected second one.. it was missing a comma at the end of:
    "start": "node file1.js",